# Jquery multiple choice quiz using clickable buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm a beginner in Jquery.
I want to create a multiple choice quiz with over 30 questions. Each questions has four options assigned to 4 clickable CSS buttons - NOT radio buttons). The user clicks on just one button to make the choice. Each button would fire a script (in a click-function), and depending on the button clicked, (eg button A)  a point or no points is assigned to a variable in memory, then a new set of questions is automatically paged in to replace the former set. This goes on to the end of the bank of 30 questions, when total scores are then (and only then) displayed on screen.
I want the same buttons (A,B, C,D) to remain displayed on the screen throughout, without having CSS rewrite them, but each button be re-assigned a different correct or incorrect script (eg, this time question C is correct and, if clicked, awards 1 point) based on the next bank of questions and the correct button choice for the answer in that new bank.

It's easy to copy 30 banks of questions with their different questions into the html file, but there must be a more elegant way to switch the code from one button to the other, depending on the correct button to click, without having to use so many lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use two arrays, one in which you put the correct and incorrect code, and then another 2D array, for each question and for each answer an index for the array with the code.

When you arrive at a certain question, loop through that part of the 2D array and attach the code to each answer.

For example:

```
var codeArray = [notCorrect, correct]; // your functions you have defined, that are called when the answer is correct or not correct.
var answerArray = [
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0], 

  // ... etc ...

  [1, 0, 0, 0],
];

$('.button').click (function (event) {
  // get questionNumber and answerNumber
  codeArray[answerArray[questionNumber-1][answerNumber-1]](); // call the function, and mind the 0 indices!
}
```

---

**EDIT**, more info:

An array can be defined like this:

```
var myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

You can put any values in each 'slot'. In my example, I am only using `1`'s and `0`'s. To access these numbers in the array, use square brackets (`[]`).

You can also put functions into arrays (in my example, the `codeArray`. You can even give anonymous functions, like this:

```
var codeArray = [function () { alert("Not correct"); }, function () { alert("Correct!"); }];
```

The last few lines of code is the click handler for any `.button` click. If a user clicks a button with the class `button`, this function is triggered.

I hope this helped enough, if you don't understand any of this, please read some JavaScript books, and become a little more educated.

Comment: This seems to make sense, however I'm not that familiar with pulling data from an array and don't understand what you mean about the coding for the loop and for each button. Could you expand a little on that please?
Thanks again for your help.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way would be to add a javascript property to the checkbox...

e.g.

```
element.answer = true;
...
elements.filter(function(cb, index){      return cb.answer === true && cb.checked; });
```

Comment: It would have the added benefit of being closed and only available in said deleted closure no there would be no way to creep the scope without reading memory. See my library for some example http://netjs.codeplex.com ... see how I do the sealed polyfill... do the same just hide the closure from which you declare the function from global access and possibly remove it from the global access to ensure that it cannot be debugged.